# Prove unstable singularity is limit of some solution when $t\to-\infty$.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, dynamical-systems, stability-in-odes, stability-theory

Consider an ODE $x'=f(x)$, where $f:U\to\mathbb{R}^n$ is $C^1$ and $U$ is some open subset of $R^n$.

Supose $x^*\in U$ is an unstable singularity of the ODE, that is:

$f(x^*)=0$ and there is a neighborhood $W$ of $x^*$ such that there are solutions with initial condition arbitrarily close to $x^*$ that leave $W$.

How can I prove that there is at least one non-trivial solution $x$ such that $\displaystyle \lim_{t\to-\infty}x(t)=x^*$?

I'm not sure this existence is necessary, but every example of unstable singularity that I know of satisfies this property.

My approach so far was the following:

$~$

Let $\Phi(t,x)$ be the flow of the ODE and WLOG we can consider $W=B(x^*,r)$ for some radius $r>0$.

By continuity, the hypothesis of there being initial conditions $x_n\to x^*$ that leave $W$ implies that for each $n$ there is a $t_n>0$ where $\Phi(t_n,x_n)=c_n\in S$ where $S$ is the border of $W$.

Since $S$ is compact, by using a subsequence if necessary, we can consider $c_n\to c\in S$.

We can also rewrite $\Phi(t_n,x_n)=c_n$ as $\Phi(-t_n,c_n)=x_n$.

So, in short, I have the following relevant properties:

$\bullet~c_n\to c$ ;

$\bullet~\Phi(-t_n,c_n)=x_n$ ;

$\bullet~x_n\to x^*$ ;

$\bullet~\Phi$ is differentiable (with respect to both $t$ and $x$) .

The last step would be to show that $x(t):=\Phi(t,c)$ is the solution we are looking for, but I couldn't manage to do it.

Comment: I do not think it is true. Consider $\dot x = x$.

Comment: The solutions would be of the form $c\cdot e^t$, which goest to $0$ (the singularity) when $t\to-\infty$. The linear case $x'=Ax$ I know is true because both the existence of a non-trivial solution $x$ such that $\displaystyle\lim_{t\to-\infty}x(t)\to 0$ and $0$ being unstable are equivalent to $A$ having a eigenvalue with positive real part.

Answer (score 1):

Turns out it is not only false, but also, unlike I said, there is a linear counterexample in $\mathbb{R}^2$:

$x'=
\begin{bmatrix}
0 & 1\\
0 & 0
\end{bmatrix}x
$ .

All the solutions are of the form:
$x(t)=
\begin{bmatrix}
x_0+ty_0\\
y_0
\end{bmatrix}~$ , with $~x_0,y_0\in\mathbb{R}$ .

Clearly, the limit in question only converges if $y_0=0$, in that case $x(t)\equiv
\begin{bmatrix}
x_0\\
y_0
\end{bmatrix}$ , but we were looking for non-trivial solutions, so there are none.